# Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed

Tags: marketing-cloud

```
SELECT 
'HelloWorld!' AS Filter,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ENT.[Reporting_Sent]) AS [Sent Units],
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ENT.[Reporting_Bounce])
FROM ENT.[Reporting_Sent]
```

I am trying to create a DE but getting an error saying that "Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed"

How can I display two counts from two tables into one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  'HelloWorld!' AS Filter,
  Sent.Count AS [Sent Units],
  Bounce.Count AS [Bounced]
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM ENT.[Reporting_Sent]
) AS Sent
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM ENT.[Reporting_Bounce]
) AS Bounce
```